# Looking for well-rounded graphing tool

Tags: math-software

I am working my way through a few MOOCs, among them is a course in complex analysis, and I am looking for a versatile tool which could be applied to a variety of mathematical disciplines. It would be great to be able to model functions in the complex plane as well as plot any of a number of things that could arise in other courses.

I tried to download SAGE but I was having an inordinate amount of difficulty with the program. Ultimately, I would love a user-friendly tool.